# Why is linear map injectivity defined solely using the null-space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The thing I'm wondering about is as follows:

Can we have a *non-injective* linear map $f:M\to N$, with an element $n\in N$, and elements $m_1,m_2 \in M$ such that, $f(m_1)=n$ and $f(m_2)=n$, without $m_1, m_2$ being necessarily in the null-space of $f$ defined as $\mathcal{N}(f)=\{m\in M: f(m)=0\}$? or said differently, without $n$ necessarily being $0$.

If not why?

Comment: This happens if and only if $f(m_1 - m_2) = 0$, or equivalently if and only if $m_1 - m_2$ is in the nullspace. This is why it suffices to check that the nullspace is zero when checking whether a linear map is injective.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Okay. Actually, I was more wondering about whether we can find an $n\ne0$ that satisfies $f(m_1)=n=f(m_2)$.

Comment: @Likely: Not always (for example, if $f$ is the zero map you cannot). But if $f$ is not the zero map, and it is not injective, then you can always do so: find $x\neq 0$ such that $f(x)=0$. Then find $y$ with $f(y)\neq 0$. Now note that $m_1=y$ and $m_2=x+y$ have the property you want.

Comment: @Likely: yes, this follows straightforwardly from what I said. Take $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto x$. Then $f(1, 1) = f(1, 2) = 1$, for example.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Okay, thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to define injectivity of linear transformations the same way we define it for all functions: a linear transformation $T$ is injective if and only if $T(m_1)=T(m_2)$ implies $m_1=m_2$.

Now, it is clear that if the linear transformation is injective, then since we know that by virtue of being linear we must have $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$, then by virtue of being injective we will also have that if $T(m)=\mathbf{0}$, then $m=\mathbf{0}$; that is, the nullspace is trivial. This condition is certainly *necessary*.

But your question is: how come it is sufficient as well? That’s a good question: it doesn’t happen in Calculus, for sure. We can have a function that is not injective, but where there is only one number going to $0$ (for example, $f(x)=x^2$).

The key is the **linearity**. Essentially, because we are working with a vector space, we can shift everything down to $\mathbf{0}$. Just like we can picture vectors as arrows that either start at the origin or somewhere else, we can “shift” the check to $0$.

Say we want to know whether $T(m_1)=T(m_2)$. Well, we can check instead whether $T(m_1)-T(m_2)=\mathbf{0}$, of course; but because $T$ is linear, this is the same as $T(m_1-m_2)=\mathbf{0}$. That is, we can check whether $T$ takes the same value at $m_1$ and at $m_2$ by checking whether $T$ takes the value $\mathbf{0}$ at $m_1-m_2$, by shifting everything by $-m_2$.

Since $T(m_1)=T(m_2)$ if and only if $T(m_1-m_2)=\mathbf{0}$ (all the processes above can be reversed), and since $m_1=m_2$ if and only if $m_1-m_2=\mathbf{0}$, we get a nice chain of implications:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(m_1)=T(m_2) &\iff T(m_1)-T(m_2)=\mathbf{0}\\
&\iff T(m_1-m_2)=\mathbf{0}\\
&\iff m_1-m_2\in \mathcal{N}(T).
\end{align*}$$
And
$$m_1=m_2\iff m_1-m_2=\mathbf{0}.$$
Putting the two together, we can replace the conditions in the definition of “injective.” Rather than asking that “if $T(m_1)=T(m_2)$ then $m_1=m_2$”, we can ask “if $m_1-m_2\in\mathcal{N}(T)$, then $m_1-m_2=\mathbf{0}$.”

But now... we don’t actually need to write the vector $m_1-m_2$ as a difference. The only thing that matters is that we are asking that “if a vector is mapped to $\mathbf{0}$, then that vector is the zero vector.”

So we get:

**Theorem.** If $T$ is a linear transformation, then the following are equivalent:

1. If $T(m_1)=T(m_2)$, then $m_1=m_2$.
2. If $T(x)=\mathbf{0}$, then $x=\mathbf{0}$.
3. $T$ is injective.
4. $\mathcal{N}(T)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$.

So the fact that we can check just the nullspace is a *feature*. It makes checking injectivity easier.

As to your question... if $T$ is the zero map (sends every vector to $\mathbf{0}$), then it is not injective (unless you are working in the zero vector space), then of course you cannot find $v\neq\mathbf{0}$ and $m_1\neq m_2$ with $T(m_1)=v=T(m_2)$. But in every other case, you can.

If $T$ is not the zero map, then there exists $x$ with $T(x)=v\neq\mathbf{0}$. Note that $x\neq\mathbf{0}$ (because $\mathbf{0}$ always maps to $\mathbf{0}$). If there exists $y\neq \mathbf{0}$ with $T(y)=\mathbf{0}$, then let $m_1=x$ and $m_2=x+y$. Then $m_2\neq m_1$, and $$T(m_2)=T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y) = T(m_1)+\mathbf{0}=T(m_1).$$

But now the problem is that if you pick your $v$ badly, then it could be that $\{x\in V\mid T(x)=v\}$ is empty! And then you won’t be able to detect injectivity at all.

So you *could* try defining a kind of “nullspace” with other vectors. But (i) It may be empty; and so (ii) useless. The only kind of single “target” you can use that you are guaranteed will work to check injectivity is the usual nullspace. No other “target” will do.

Answer (score 0):

(while corresponding statements all apply to groups and modules in general, I will focus on vector spaces).

Theorem. Let k be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ (so k can be the real numbers or the complex numbers for instance), and $f:U\to V$ be a linear map of k-vector spaces. Then if $u,w\in U$, $u-w\in ker(f):= \{m\in U : f(m) = 0\}$ (typically we use ker(f) and call it the "kernel of f" in this context) if and only if f(u) = f(w).

proof. =>: So $f(u-w) = 0$. f is additive ($f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$) so f(-w) = -f(w) and $f(u - w) = f(u) + f(-w) = f(u) - f(w) = 0$ and thus $f(u) = f(w)$.

<=: $f(u) = f(w)$ gives that $f(u) - f(w) = 0$. Again f is additive, so $f(u - w) = f(u) - f(w)$, which we know is zero. So $f(u-w) = 0$, which is what it means to say that $u - w\in ker(f)$.