# Example of a non injective linear map $T : V \rightarrow W$ satisfying $\dim(\operatorname{image}(T)) = \dim(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : V \rightarrow W$ for this question. ($V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.)

I was looking at this theorem:

$\dim(W) \lt \dim (V) \implies T$ is not injective

And then I wondered if the below might be true:

T is not injective and $\dim(W) \ge \dim(V) \implies \dim(\operatorname{image}(T)) < \dim(V)$

I got stuck trying to prove the above statement so I'm looking for a counterexample to disprove it. Any proof or disproof of the above statement is also welcome.

Comment: This seems true to me (in finite-dimensional vector spaces at least), since you can consider $T\colon V\to W$ as a linear map with a different codomain, namely $T\colon V\to T(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Rank-Nullity theorem $${\rm dim(image}(T))={\rm dim}(V)-{\rm dim(kernel}(T)).$$ If $T$ is not injective then ${\rm dim(kernel}(T))>0$. Therefore if $T$ is not injective ${\rm dim(image}(T))<{\rm dim}(V)$.

Comment: Is it possible to map two or more distinct nonzero vectors to the same nonzero vector while retaining $dim(im(T)) = dim(V)$? If that is possible then we would not be able to use the Rank-Nullity theorem to immediately prove the statement.

Comment: If ${\rm dim(image}(T) ={\rm dim} V$ then T will be injective.

Comment: proof for above: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977138/why-is-linear-map-injectivity-defined-solely-using-the-null-space

Answer (score 0):

Without any information on the codomain, you have $\dim(\text{im(T)})<
\dim(V)$.

Indeed, (in finite dimensions) by rank-nullity $\dim(V)=\dim(\text {im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))>\dim(\text{im}(T))$.